# Ionic ngFor duplicates list items

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Help guys. I am building some type of todo application that uses SQLite for storage.
My HomePage is where i show the list of todos. It looks something like `*ngFor="let todo of itemList"` The list shows all right but when ever i go to another page, lets say i go to the page where i add a new Todo and the process is done and i set page back to root, then the list of todos i have duplicate themselves. If i exit the app and open it again everything comes back to normal. I read about it somewhere but i am not exactly sure of the details, the person said it had to do with subscribing and unsubscribing. I would appreciate it if someone could help me out. Thanks in advance.

Here is the component code

```
public itemList : Array<Object>;

this.todoService.read().then((response: any)=>{
   this.itemList = <Array<Object>> response;
});
```

The service that returns the data looks like

```
read(){    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.sqlite.create({
        name: DB_NAME,
        location: 'default'
      })
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {  
        db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todos(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(32), date VARCHAR(32), time VARCHAR(32), datetime VARCHAR(32))', {})
          .then(() => console.log("Created Table OR NOT"))
          .catch(e => this.presentAlert(e));

        db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM todos ORDER BY id DESC', {})
        .then((response) => {
          if(response.rows.length > 0){
            for(var i=0; i < response.rows.length; i++){
              this.my_todos.push({
                id:response.rows.item(i).id, 
                name:response.rows.item(i).name,
                date:response.rows.item(i).date,
                time:response.rows.item(i).time, 
                datetime:response.rows.item(i).datetime
              })
            }
          }
          resolve(this.my_todos);
        })
        .catch(e => this.presentAlert(JSON.stringify(e)));
      })
      .catch(e => this.presentAlert(JSON.stringify(e)));
    }); 

  }
```

Comment: I would appreciate if you share the code ;)?

Comment: everytime on init are you getting todos[] and pushing it to itemList[]? or you are just assigning todos[] to itemList[]. Please share the code where you are assigning data to itemList[].

Comment: Thanks for replying guys. I just uploaded the codes. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: put `this.my_todos=[]` at the top of read method

Comment: You mean i should do it like this?
public my_todos : [];
`this.todoService.read().then((response: any)=>{
  this.my_todos = response;
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your read() before you push, you need to ensure *this.my_todos* is [], if not it will keep adding and hence you have the duplicates.

```
//this.my_todos may not be [] here.
this.my_todos.push({
            id:response.rows.item(i).id, 
            name:response.rows.item(i).name,
            date:response.rows.item(i).date,
            time:response.rows.item(i).time, 
            datetime:response.rows.item(i).datetime
          })
```

set *this.my_todos* to an empty array before you push the data as shown below.

```
read(){
this.my_todos = [];  //this one  
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```